# How to trim video without losing frames using ffmpeg(3.2.15) or any php tool

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-processing, trim

I can see a lot of solutions for trimming videos using ffmpeg but all of them either drop a few frames, audio is out of sync or video is a few seconds longer than specified. I have tried pretty much everything I could find and nothing worked. Only one solution worked and it was re-encoding but if the video was longer than 5sec it took too long.

A few combinations I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -ss 00:00:15.000 -t 00:00:10.000 -c:v copy -c:a copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero test-1.mp4 //drops starting frames

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15.000 -t 00:00:10.000 -i test.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero test-1.mp4 //additional few seconds to the specified video length
```

If you can share any other libraries or APIs I could use to achieve my goal it would be much appreciated. As far as I researched ffmpeg was the most popular solution but in this case it doesn't work because I need the trimming to be precise.

Comment: Why use such an old FFmpeg? With stream copy cuts must be made on keyframes. If you need more accuracy then you must re-encode.

Comment: because my server's Debian version allows only 3.2.15 as the latest ffmpeg version

Comment: You can always [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) (assuming you can install dependency packages).

Comment: @llogan, FFMpeg is not that old. Version 5 Released 2 month ago :)